# Is there a way to see all the AGE created tables?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

For example in a PostgreSQL database, all the other tables can be seen using

```
\dt
```

Or with

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables;
```

And we know that AGE creates its own label tables, vertex table, edge table.

How can I see those tables, and how can I query for them to view them along with their all columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly , we can make use out of the concept that for each graph you create using AGE to work with , AGE creates a separate schema for this graph that has it's related tables , and this schema named exactly the same as the name of your created graph.

so you can easily select the created tables behind the scenes from the `pg_catalog` , `information_schema` tables using the graph name as our schema name.

we created a graph through age as ,

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.create_graph('your_first_graph');
```

you can go and see it's related tables that created for it behind the scenes in both `pg_catalog.pg_tables` and `information_schema.tables`,

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
WHERE schemaname = 'your_first_graph';
```

and ,

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'your_first_graph';
```

And if you aim to query them and observe their entries you can use `<your graph name>.<desired table name>` and do your queries for example ,

```
SELECT *
FROM your_first_graph._ag_label_edge ;
```

Actually if you are not interested in detailed table information provided such as tablespace_oid , oid ..etc , you can directly the `ag_label` to get tables name  , type and graph to which they are related as,

```
SELECT * FROM ag_label ;
```

Answer (score 2):

`ag_catalog` contains all the metadata used by Apache AGE. `ag_graphs` is contained in `ag_catalog` and it stores the information/namespaces about all the graphs present in the database. `ag_label` stores the data. So to fetch all the tables, you do:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_label;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_label;
```

to get a similar result in AGE, for example:

```
       name       | graph | id | kind |           relation           |        seq_name
------------------+-------+----+------+------------------------------+-------------------------
 _ag_label_vertex | 16944 |  1 | v    | "Demo"._ag_label_vertex      | _ag_label_vertex_id_seq
 _ag_label_edge   | 16944 |  2 | e    | "Demo"._ag_label_edge        | _ag_label_edge_id_seq
 Person           | 16944 |  3 | v    | "Demo"."Person"              | Person_id_seq
 REL              | 16944 |  4 | e    | "Demo"."REL"                 | REL_id_seq
 KNOWS            | 16944 |  5 | e    | "Demo"."KNOWS"               | KNOWS_id_seq
```

where the `kind` column tells you if it is a vertex `v` or an edge `e`, with their labels shown in the `name` column.

[Here is a regress test](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/88ead70e9bdc8961c25717890433df5cb0acd967/regress/expected/catalog.out) to check the different variations of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Table `ag_graph` stores names and namespaces of all the graphs.

```
SELECT * FROM ag_graph;
```

Table `ag_label` stores all the data (labels, relations, sequences etc).

```
SELECT * FROM ag_label;
```

To see all the vertices and edges:

```
SELECT * FROM <graph_name>._ag_label_vertex;
SELECT * FROM <graph_name>._ag_label_edge;
```

To see all vertices and edges with a specific label:

```
SELECT * FROM <graph_name>."<label_name>";
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM ag_label;` gets this done.

However, remember to **SET** `search_path`  before running the query else simply run `SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.ag_label;`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following query to view the table

```
SELECT oid, * FROM ag_catalog.ag_label;
```

Table Results would be as follow:

```
  oid   |        name       | graph | id | kind |        relation          |
----------+-------------------+-------+----+------+--------------------------+
   16950  | _age_label_vertex | 16937 |  1 | v    | database.ag_label_vertex |
   16963  | _age_label_edge   | 16937 |  2 | e    | database.ag_label_edge   |
   16975  | Country           | 16937 |  3 | v    | database."Country"       |
   16987  | City              | 16937 |  4 | v    | database."City"          |
   16999  | has_city          | 16937 |  5 | e    | database.has_city    |
```

where:

- oid : An unique Postgres identifier per label ;
- name: The name of the label ;
- graph: Oid from ag_graph ;
- id : The id for the label, it is unique for each graph ;
- kind : Shows if it is a vertex “v” or an edge “e” ;
- relation : Schema qualified name of table name for label.

Reference:
https://matheusfarias03.github.io/AGE-quick-guide/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this guide [Guide](https://matheusfarias03.github.io/AGE-quick-guide/)

For creating a graph, you can use the create_graph function, located in the ag_catalog namespace:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.create_graph('graph_name');
```

The data for a label is stored in the ag_label and use can use this query to view the available labels:

```
SELECT oid, * FROM ag_catalog.ag_label;
```

where, oid : An unique Postgres identifier per label.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've loaded `AGE` and set your search path to `ag_catalog`, you can use this query to display all the labels.
`SELECT * FROM ag_label;` and this will display all the nodes and vertices in the ag_catalog.
You could also use `SELECT * FROM ag_graph;` to display all the graph names.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, the tables created by the AGE extension are stored in ag_catalog schema.

for example:

to see all the tables in the ag_catalog schema use the following query:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'ag_catalog';
```

to view the columns of a particular table in ag_catalog you have to replace your table with the actual name of the table you want to view:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'ag_catalog' AND table_name = 'your_table_name';
```

if you want to view all the tables and their columns together, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT t.table_name, c.column_name, c.data_type
FROM information_schema.tables t
JOIN information_schema.columns c ON t.table_name = c.table_name AND t.table_schema = c.table_schema
WHERE t.table_schema = 'ag_catalog';
```

Answer (score 0):

`ag_graph` stores the list of all the graphs, and `ag_label` stores the list of all the additional tables created by Apache AGE.

```
SELECT * FROM ag_graph;
```

This is the sample output of the above code.

```
demodb=# SELECT * FROM ag_graph;
 graphid |        name         |      namespace
---------+---------------------+---------------------
   66676 | graph               | graph
  137025 | bitnine_global_inic | bitnine_global_inic
  137077 | test_graph          | test_graph
   75557 | age_graph           | age_graph
(4 rows)
```

.

```
SELECT * FROM ag_label;
```

This is the sample output of the above code.

```
demodb=# SELECT * FROM ag_label;
       name       | graph  | id | kind |               relation               |        seq_name
------------------+--------+----+------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------
 _ag_label_vertex |  66676 |  1 | v    | graph._ag_label_vertex               | _ag_label_vertex_id_seq
 _ag_label_edge   |  66676 |  2 | e    | graph._ag_label_edge                 | _ag_label_edge_id_seq
 student          |  66676 |  8 | v    | graph.student                        | student_id_seq
 _ag_label_vertex |  75557 |  1 | v    | age_graph._ag_label_vertex           | _ag_label_vertex_id_seq
 _ag_label_edge   |  75557 |  2 | e    | age_graph._ag_label_edge             | _ag_label_edge_id_seq
 _ag_label_vertex | 137025 |  1 | v    | bitnine_global_inic._ag_label_vertex | _ag_label_vertex_id_seq
 _ag_label_edge   | 137025 |  2 | e    | bitnine_global_inic._ag_label_edge   | _ag_label_edge_id_seq
 Country          | 137025 |  3 | v    | bitnine_global_inic."Country"        | Country_id_seq
 City             | 137025 |  4 | v    | bitnine_global_inic."City"           | City_id_seq
 has_city         | 137025 |  5 | e    | bitnine_global_inic.has_city         | has_city_id_seq
 _ag_label_vertex | 137077 |  1 | v    | test_graph._ag_label_vertex          | _ag_label_vertex_id_seq
 _ag_label_edge   | 137077 |  2 | e    | test_graph._ag_label_edge            | _ag_label_edge_id_seq
(12 rows)
```

In the above output, rows with names starting without an underscore are user-generated labels.

You can query from the specific labels using the relation name given in `relation` column.

```
SELECT * FROM graph._ag_label_vertex;
SELECT * FROM bitnine_global_inic."City";
```

Answer (score -1):

To see the tables and to query them in the column mode yo can follow the following steps:

1. List the Specific tables in and store them as graph data.
2. Use the '\d' in sql to view columns of a specific AGE table.
3. View all columns is the related tables in the current schema.

Answer (score -1):

To be able to see all the AGE tables created,You can us the following command:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.ag_label;
```

here is a sample output result to show you all the tables created:

```
      name       | graph | id | kind |          relation           |        seq_name         
------------------+-------+----+------+-----------------------------+-------------------------
 _ag_label_vertex | 41520 |  1 | v    | test_graph._ag_label_vertex | _ag_label_vertex_id_seq
 _ag_label_edge   | 41520 |  2 | e    | test_graph._ag_label_edge   | _ag_label_edge_id_seq
 Person           | 41520 |  3 | v    | test_graph."Person"         | Person_id_seq
 coworkers        | 41520 |  4 | e    | test_graph.coworkers        | coworkers_id_seq
 managers         | 41520 |  5 | e    | test_graph.managers         | managers_id_seq
 engineers        | 41520 |  6 | e    | test_graph.engineers        | engineers_id_seq
 reports          | 41520 |  7 | e    | test_graph.reports          | reports_id_seq
(7 rows)
```